# SUM cells until current cell where value of another column is the same

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula

I need to SUM all values in the column till the current cell, where the values in a different column are the same.

Example:

```
------------------------------------------------------
| FIRST   | SECOND   | SUM                            |
------------------------------------------------------
| VALUE A | NUMBER 1 | NUMBER 1                       |
------------------------------------------------------
| VALUE A | NUMBER 2 | NUMBER 1 + NUMBER 2            |
------------------------------------------------------
| VALUE B | NUMBER 3 | NUMBER 3                       |
-------------------------------------------------------
| VALUE B | NUMBER 4 | NUMBER 3 + NUMBER 4            |
-------------------------------------------------------
| VALUE B | NUMBER 5 | NUMBER 3 + NUMBER 4 + NUMBER 5 |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

The first column has strings, the second numbers and the first holds the results.

Answer (score 0):

Write an if statement to do this. Compare the value of the first column between the current and previous rows, if they have the same value add previous sum and current value together, otherwise the sum becomes the current value.

In code, this would be the formula in C3

```
 =if(exact(A3,A2),C2+B3,B3)
```